# How to determine if publishing to SiteEditable/XPM-enabled site?

Tags: experience-manager, templating

How can one determine if the Template is being published to a site with SiteEdit/XPM enabled?

When Experience Manager is installed, Publication Target in the CME has a flag "Enable for inline editing".  When this flag is selected a tab with XPM configuration options appears.

Is it possible to access the value of this flag in a TBB?  If not, is there some other way to determine if a given Component or Page is being rendered and published to a SiteEditable location?  One of I thought of is by specifying the list of publications having SiteEdit enabled in the parameters of a template.  Is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Credit on this solution goes to Eric Huiza.

Here's an Extension Method for the Publication Target that reads the Application Data to check if the target is SiteEditEnabled:

```cs
public static bool IsSiteEditEnabled(this PublicationTarget target)
{
    try
    {
        if (target == null)
            return true;
        ApplicationData appData = target.LoadApplicationData("SiteEdit");
        string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(appData.Data);
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(data);

        XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
        nsManager.AddNamespace("se", "http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit");

        XmlNode seNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/se:configuration/se:PublicationTarget/se:EnableSiteEdit",
                         nsManager);
        if (seNode != null && seNode.InnerText.Equals("true"))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // Quick and dirty fix
        return false;
    }
}
```

Add this to your Template project, and then you can do something along these lines:

```cs
if(engine.PublishingContext.PublicationTarget.IsSiteEditEnabled())
    // do something for SE enabled targets
```

**EDIT**

With SDL Web 8 you can determine this by using `TargetType.IsPreviewCapable(Publication)` - see example [here](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/blob/92a7e89a95342723d876af62e0c054e58825b68d/Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates/Common/Utility.cs).

Comment: This might not work on Web 8 using Business Process Types! (I have not tested this!)

Comment: Indeed, with Web 8 the approach is different. You should use TargetType.IsPreviewCapable - see "IsXpmEnabled" method in https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/blob/92a7e89a95342723d876af62e0c054e58825b68d/Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates/Common/Utility.cs

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Razor Mediator to build your layout you can use its built-in function IsSiteEditEnabled.  The Razor Mediator v1.3.3 documentation has the following example.

@if (IsSiteEditEnabled) {

```
<div>Component Title: @Component.Title</div>
```

}

Comment: Thanks for answering and welcome to the community, Les Dancsecs!